# Semantic relations between set of words

Tags: java, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

If I have a set of words (DBpedia resources) storing in arraylist 
how can I build a SPARQL query to find all possible direct on indirect relation between these terms?
the major problem is I don't know what's the relation type that I'm searching for.

suppose that my arraylist contains 3 words, France,Paris, Europe
How can I write a query that returns the direct relation (or indirect relation of 2 hops) between France-Paris ,Paris-Europe and France-Europe

hope that I clear up what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use `VALUES` to set a variable to your set of resources, but do it *twice*, once for each end of the relation. Then use a variable as a predicate to find what the relation is. Something like:

```
SELECT ?resource1 ?p1 ?intermediary ?p2 ?resource2
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?resource1 { :Paris :France :Europe }
  VALUES ?resource2 { :Paris :France :Europe }
  FILTER(?resource1 != ?resource2)

  {
    ?resource1 ?p1 ?resource2
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?resource1 ?p1 ?intermediary.
    ?intermediary ?p2 ?resource2.
  }
}
```

The results are:

[image: screenshot of the results table]